# Custom subdomain with Heroku for WordPress blog shows herokuapp.com URL on clicking the post

Tags: wordpress, heroku, dns, subdomain

I have a Rails app for root domain `www.xyz.com` which is hosted on Heroku. It works perfectly: all the URLs and products are shown with the proper custom domain.

I have created blog using WordPress which is a separate Heroku app and hosted on the subdomain `blog.xyz.com`. The landing page works fine. However when I click on any post the URL changes to `*.herokuapp.com`.

I have added a CNAME record in GoDaddy for the blog subdomain and added custom domain with following command:

```
heroku domains:add --app heroku-blog-wordpress-app-name blog.xyz.com
```

How do I get WordPress to use the correct domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with DNS. WordPress just doesn't know what domain it should use when it generates URLs.

1. Log into WordPress
2. Navigate to **Settings** → **General**
3. Update the **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** values to use your `blog.xyz.com` domain
4. Save your settings

WordPress should now build URLs using the correct domain.